# Will asp.net-mvc ajax related requests count as page views in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, iis

Will asp.net-mvc ajax related requests count as page views in IIS?

Does it make a different on the response type of the request? i.e. json versus ...

Answer (score 3):

IIS logs do not have a separate column for content-type (text/html, application/json). Views - anytime IIS responds to an HTTP request - will certainly show up in the log.

Any differentiation between AJAX/non-AJAX requests would need to be done by your log analyzer based on parsing out specific AJAX-requested URLs.